# Creating installers in .net

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, windows-installer

> I want to create a installer which
>   would just dump few files and folders
>   at a location specified by user. But
>   the problem is these files are
>   required to be picked up from a fixed
>   source folder and then the installer
>   is build. Also, these files may change
>   any time and then again a new version
>   of the installer is required to be
>   created.

I want to do this in .Net using Setup and Deployment project. I'm not sure how to do this. 
Do I need to create another class library project with a Setup Poject?

Actually the installer will have two options:

1. Simply extract the files at the specified location
2. Embed the files (the HTML files) in the intranet sharepoint site.

Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: Check out http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/authoring.htm

Comment: I think that the WiX toolkit is better than a Setup and Deployment project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a windows application with several forms doing all the required stuff. This windows application behaved like a Setup.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a Self-extracting ZIP file.

You can build one with [DotNetZip](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dotnetzip).  It requires .NET on the target machine. It unpacks files to a user-specified location, and then optionally runs a program that you specify.  That program could be one of the files unpacked, or could be something else.

To create a self-extracting archive using DotNetZip, this is the code:

```
// create the SFX
using (ZipFile zip1 = new ZipFile())
{
    zip1.AddFile(filename1, "");       // extract to toplevel
    zip1.AddFile(filename2, "subdir"); // extract to subdir
    zip1.AddFile(filename3, "subdir");
    zip1.Comment = "This will be embedded into a self-extracting exe";
    zip1.AddEntry("Readme.txt", "This is Update XXX of product YYY");
    var sfxOptions = new SelfExtractorSaveOptions {
        Flavor = SelfExtractorFlavor.WinFormsApplication,
        Quiet = false,  // false == show a UI
        DefaultExtractDirectory = UnpackDirectory
    }
    zip1.SaveSelfExtractor(SfxFileToCreate, sfxOptions);
}
```

The UI of the generated SFX looks like this:

[image]

The SFX does not rely on MSI, so there is no uninstall option. This may or may not be a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good article on Setup and Deployment: http://aspalliance.com/622_StepbyStep_Process_of_Creating_a_Setup_and_Deployment_Project.all

Answer (score 1):

Built in setup and deployment projects are a total pain in my experience, so instead I use [Advanced installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com). Its cheap and easy to use.  I think they have a free edition also.